# NavigationBar setShadowImage not always working

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set a custom shadow image for the navigation bar in my table views, but it's only showing in some views. I've created a super class to set the styles for my table views.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set navigation bar background
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbarbackground.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // Set navigation bar shadow imag
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbarshadow.png"]];
```

In the view I see at starting my app, no shadow is showed. But when I touch the [+] button in my navigation bar to open my '*add new item*' table view, it does show a shadow.

Could someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: You should use the appearance proxy.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but with the same result.

Comment: Be sure that `self.navigationController` in `viewDidLoad` is not `nil`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Appearance proxy should work.

Just call it somewhere (e.g. in your AppDelegate) upon startup.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
    [self customizeAppearance];
    return YES;
}

- (void) customizeAppearance 
{
    // Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbarbackground"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // Set the shadow image for *all* UINavigationBars
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbarshadow.png"]];  

    //add other appearance stuff here...
}
```

However if you create a storyboard with multiple UINavigationController's in it and a bunch of segue's pushing navigation controller's you might get a corrupt view controller structure which might be the problem here.

Another possible issue might be the `Clip Subviews` option of a Navigation Bar somewhere in your nib file or you storyboard. Make sure it is turned off if you want the shadow (image)!

[image: ClipSubviews]

By the way, if you use imageNamed you don't need to include the file extension.

Comment: Wow thanks! The unchecking Clip Subviews did the trick. The reason I put the styling in a super class is that I wanted to keep all the styling in one place.

Answer (score 9):

you need to set custom `backgroudImage` for UINavigationBar, then the `shadowImage` can work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-iphone.png"]];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. Should using the appearance proxy have a different result than using this in every table view?:
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbarbackground.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbarshadow.png"]];