# Missing drop shadow under UINavigationBar in combination with UITableView

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uinavigationbar

When I try to add a custom background to a navigation bar, their is no drop shadow on top of the table view. In the subviews everything is fine.

Here is my code I use.

```
// Create resizable images
UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"]
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    
// Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    // Customize NavBar Shadow
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:nil];
```

Not existing drop shadow

[image: My navigation bar]

Existing drop shadow

[image: Sub Views]

Update:
Found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644641/navigationbar-setshadowimage-not-always-working), but does not work. I have done it exactly in the same way :-(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it, by reimplementing the the navigation controller. The view hierarchy looked like this.

```
UIView 
+- Navigation View
+- Table View
```

I changed my UIView to an table view and added this to the UINavigation Controller. That fixed the missing shadow issue.

Answer (score 1):

replace

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:nil];`

with

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeShadowImage"]];`

And it's for iOS 6.0 and later.

Comment: Tested it, but still not working. I get now a new shadow in the sub views. ![New Shadow](http://cl.ly/image/1l2R1h352H25)

Comment: Don't you want that blue shadow? What exactly is not working?

Comment: No I don't want the blue shadow. I used it only to distinguish it from the standard one. My App has 2 Screens. Main Screen is a navigation bar with an table view. Their is **no** shadow. The second screen is detail view with a navigation bar on top. Their **is** a shadow. The only thing what I want to achieve is, that I get a shadow on both screens.

Answer (score 1):

I followed @madcat's answer. In my case the UITableView or UITableViewController (embedded in a Container View) had to be above the Navigation Bar (dragged onto view) in the hierarchy. Like that the Navigation Bar was drawn with the shadow after/over the UITableView/Container

Comment: This is very illogical on Apple's part, but correct. +1